# index match - show results if date is within 30 days?

Tags: excel, formula

i am trying to use an index match to check if any of my suppliers are set to inactive. In column B i have the name of supplier and in column J it says whether the account is active or Inactive.

If the account is inactive i want to show the supplier name. i want to display all results, so if there are more than one account set to inactive then show all. I am doing this using row function and am using an index match with a couple of if functions to try and get me my result.

The problem I get at the moment is I am receiving an #N/A error and im not sure what im doing wrong.
Can someone please show me where I am going wrong.

```
=INDEX(SupplierTracking!B20:B10004, MATCH(0, COUNTIFS($C$18:C18, SupplierTracking!B20:B10004,SupplierTracking!J20:J10004,"=Inactive"), 0))
```

Comment: sorry the vba was a mistake

Comment: I posted an answer but I notice that your problem title refers to "if date is within 30 days" but you don't mention that in the text.....so I ignored that part, is it relevant?

Comment: The function you have does not make sense to me.  Can you paste some sample data, such that we see your input and are able to achieve your desired output given the input?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're are putting that formula in C19 and copying down - also that there might be duplicate suppliers in column B and you only want to list each one once if "inactive"?

The problem with your formula is that the `COUNTIFS` function always returns `#VALUE!` error because the ranges are differently sized, which isn't allowed in `COUNTIFS`, this solution with modified syntax should do what you want in C19

`=IFERROR(INDEX(SupplierTracking!B$20:B$10004, MATCH(1, (COUNTIF($C$18:C18, SupplierTracking!B$20:B$10004)=0)*(SupplierTracking!J$20:J$10004="Inactive"),0)),"")`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down as far as required

Note that if there are duplicate suppliers in the `SupplierTracking!B$20:B$10004` range then that supplier will be listed once as long as **at least one** of the listed entries has "inactive" in the corresponding row in column J

The additional `IFERROR` function means you get blanks instead of errors once valid returns are exhausted